Did Prince write the first half of his Sign O' The Times album on a plane flight?
According to Gilbert Davison:

We were on a flight from Minneapolis to Los Angeles, about a three-and-half-hour flight, and we'd been up pretty late the night before, but he wanted to go out to record. On the plane [he's] asking for pads and paper, and so I get him a notebook and pen and he starts writing, and he writes a poem, and he hands it to me. And I read it, and I go, "Well, you know, that's nice…sounds clever, good." I hand it back to him. Ten minutes, fifteen minutes later, he hands me another poem. I'm, like, "Oh yeah, that's just as good as the first." And I'm like, "Why does he keep handing me these poems?"
This goes on for the whole flight, and we land, and he says, "Do you mind if we go to the studio?"—he was always cordial—and I'm like, you know, "You can do whatever you want to do." And he says, "Well, I'll just be there for a few hours and then we'll head to the house." And so we go to the studio.
We were in there for three days, almost four days, straight. When he's finished, I go into the studio and I'm listening to the music. I asked him on the way home: "Did you have all that in your head? Not just the lyrics, not just the music, not just the melodies, but the arrangement, everything?" And he said, "Yeah, you know, I have to get it out when it's in there, or I can't sleep."
He had written [the first two album sides of] Sign o' the Times. He had basically written an album in a three-and-a half-hour plane ride.

The source is this article in GQ.

Unfortunately, Davison has got this wrong.
Sign O' The Times was notoriously the result of a long process. Initially Prince discarded several projects he was working on, and compiled tracks from them into a 3LP set called Crystal Ball in the late Fall of 1986. Those projects were Dream Factory, the final album featuring his band The Revolution, and Camille, an album by a persona he had created.
But Warner Bros. wouldn't allow a 3LP release, and they convinced Prince to reduce it to a 2LP. In early 1987, Prince removed seven of the 22 tracks from Crystal Ball, added "U Got The Look", and titled the resulting album Sign O' The Times.
If you go to Prince Vault and click through the tracks included on the first LP of that set, you'll notice that they have recording dates that are far apart. "Slow Love" dates back as far as July 1984, and was in large part not written by Prince. Meanwhile "Play In The Sunshine" dates to late November 1986, while a lot of other tracks date to Summer 1986. They mostly originate from different recording sessions, often days or weeks or months apart.

However, there is an album where Prince recorded its first half in one go: Parade. After he had returned from a short vacation to Rio De Janeiro, he returned to Studio 3 in Sunset Sound studios in Los Angeles on 15 January 1986 and started remixing several older songs, possibly for a future album project, but also to audition a new engineer, Coke Johnson. (He got hired.)
The next day (16 January) Prince worked on several new tracks and on integrating Clare Fischer's orchestrations for The Family's debut album, a side project. At the end of the session, towards the morning, Prince called out "Fresh tape!", Susan Rogers put on a new tape and they started working on "Life Can Be So Nice".
After that session ended in the morning of 17 January, and Prince had had some rest, he returned to the studio in the late afternoon. He requested that Susan Rogers put on a new tape, sat down at the drums and this ensued:

He said, "Put up a roll of tape. I'm gonna start playing drums, and when I stop, don't stop the tape. Just keep going, just let it roll." We didn't know what he was gonna do. He sat down behind the drum set and taped his lyrics up on a music stand in front of him, we pressed "record" on the tape machine, and he played the entire drum track to "Christopher Tracy's Parade."
Then he played the drum track to "New Position," then he played the drum track to "I Wonder U." Then he played the drum track to "Under The Cherry Moon." Four drum tracks in a row, all first takes. When one would stop, he'd wait a few seconds and then start the other one. And then the tape ran out.
Then he came back in and he said, "Alright, here we go! Where is my bass?" Over the next several hours he added bass, keyboards and other musical elements and then his vocals, bringing each song to life. Blending new songs with pieces of tracks he'd been crafting; he created a beautiful suite of music.
What had started in his head was now taking shape with each of the tracks getting a distinct personality and sound even though he'd visualized this entire 4 song, 10-minute sequence all in one piece.

Source: Duane Tudahl's excellent Prince and the Parade and Sign O’ The Times Era Studio Sessions: 1985-1986.

To me it seems most likely that Davison is talking about this session, even though not all the details match. I don't know about any Prince album that has a similar story, especially not in that era of his career, an era which is pretty well documented.
